# How to get documents whose array does not include "apple" element but if it includes other elements except apple then it should return the doc

Tags: arrays, mongodb

let me give an example.
There is a collection vehicle_list
`[

```
{
    "driver" : 1,


    "driver_vehicles" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Car1",
            "state" : 1
            "vehicledates" : []
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Car2",
            "vehicledates" : [ 
                {
                    "trip" : ObjectId("6374c5521e0056579430e15e"),
                    "trip_date" : "Nov 28, 2022"
                }, 
                {
                    "trip" : ObjectId("6374c3c65c106e84520e2bda"),
                    "trip_date" : "Nov 30, 2022"
                }, 
                {
                    "trip" : ObjectId("63789e73aab4b1b08dac4d23"),
                    "trip_date" : "Dec 1, 2022"
                }
            ],
            "state" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Car3"
            "vehicledates" : [ 
                {
                    "trip_id" : ObjectId("63776d5b9061c736099501ac"),
                    "trip_date" : "Dec 2, 2022"
                }
            ],
            "state" : 1
        }
    ],
}
```

]
`

What i want is to have the Driver who does not have a vehicle that does not have a trip on  `Dec 1, 2022` and also `state:1`
So i made a query

```
db.vehicle_list.find({"driver_vehicles.vehicledates.trip_date": {$nin: ["Dec 1, 2022"]},"state":1})
```

This doesn't return document `_id 1`

Now i understand that `car2` has `Dec 1, 2022` so it should not return.
But `Car1` and `Car3` doesn't have `Dec 1, 2022` and it also matches the condition `state:1` so it should return the document.
Hope you undestand what i mean. Let me know if you have any doubts.

I tried this query

```
db.vehicle_list.find({"driver_vehicles.vehicledates.trip_date": {$nin: ["Dec 1, 2022"]},"state":1})
```

This doesn't return document `_id 1`
But it doesn't return `Driver 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, I think the `$elemMatch` operator will work as what you need.

```
db.collection.find({
  "driver_vehicles": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "vehicledates.trip_date": {
        $nin: [
          "Dec 1, 2022"
        ]
      },
      "state": 1
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dWCunYWFtoy)

Comment: (Not writing this statement in the answer as didn't confirm it's correct until I find the document supported) From what I know, the query will lead to a different result if you use dot notation and with negate compare operator such as `$ne`. Thus `$elemMatch` could solve the mentioned situation.

Comment: Hi, @YongShun I just removed the last $elementMatch and changed it to "vehicledates.trip_date" now it works perfectly. Thank you so much.